# Open CSV wtih Excel from Finder

Tags: ms-office, data, csv

Is it possible to open a CSV file with Excel direct from Finder and have the data grouped into columns. I know this is possible through the "File > Import" route, but it takes a lot of time if you are working with CSVs a lot.

If I simply set Excel as the default application, it opens the data as follows:[image]

I would like to have that data in separate columns.

Comment: Please add your default language & region and format language. I have no problem to open a csv file with the data grouped properly by either double-clicking or using "open with..." in a german system & Excel. My delimiters are semicolons though...

Comment: @klanomath Thanks, but my default language and region is set. I even tried setting it to Deutsch. No luck.

Comment: Set to English/English? And which Office version do you use? 2011 or 2016? A delimiter `;` works for me (but not the `,`) without importing the csv!

Comment: @klanomath I have 2016. Same here. It works with the semicolon, but not the comma. Going the File > Import route works with the comma though. This is my question specifically. How can I open a CSV with commas from Finder (I also changed all my Region and Language settings to not include any commas.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by changing my region to the *United States* and customising the rest of my preferences.

[image]